# how to remove a column from graph

Tags: r

My data has a column that I would like to remove from the bargraph. How would I go about removing that column?

```
ggplot(data = Access.Use,aes(fill=Access)) + geom_bar(aes(x=Access, y =. 
(..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="snow3") +
ylab("Percentage of Participants") + xlab("Availability and Use") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 0.4)) + theme_bw() + 
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
panel.background = element_blank())`
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it would be to filter the data prior to plotting. I'll use the iris dataset to demonstrate.

- First lets get the basic plot with all species from the iris dataset.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

    ggplot(data = iris) + 
        geom_col(aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length,fill=Species))
```

[image]

- Now let's use `filter` from dplyr to remove one bar from the graph.

```r
    filter(iris, Species != 'virginica') %>%
        ggplot(.) +
        geom_col(aes(x=Species,y=Speal.Length,fill=Species))
```

[image]

Note: we could perhaps offer a more specific answer if we knew what type of data was in your x variable 'Access'.

Comment: thanks!! i was able to remove the column

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! Could you accept the answer please?